# How to search and replace multiple number sequences in a file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with lots of lines like this:

```
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290:7087537
cat:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290
```

Using bash programming (sed or awk or something), how can I add a 6 in front of every number after the 5th ":", only lines that begins with "cat:"?
The correct result would be this:

```
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290:7087537
cat:7066469:182:0:0:67050964:67087402:67058396
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1=="cat"{for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) $i = "6" $i} 1' file
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290:7087537
cat:7066469:182:0:0:67050964:67087402:67058396
dog:7066469:182:0:0:7050964:7087402:7058396:7079290
```

Comment: if I want to use a variable intead of $i = "6", like $i = "$var", how do I get it to expand?

Comment: Use: `awk -v var="999" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1=="cat"{for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) $i = var $i} 1' file`